# Ajax call failed with status code zero and statusText as NetworkError in IE10

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using an ajax call from javascript file.This works fine in Chrome,Firefox,IE 11.but only in IE10 the call get failed with status code as zero and status text as **NetworkError**.

Also this works fine with localhost.Only the Error occurs after made it as public host.This is not a cross domain call.
If fiddler is running along with the application then there is no any issue.working fine.Sorry for my bad English
Can you please help me?

Comment: check if Content-Length or chunk length value is valid. once I was using fiddler to mock the data i I run into such a behavior. if it's not your case be more specific :provide screenshot or even dump of response.

Comment: @ skyboyer Thanks for your comment.I solved issue.It was because of my network security settings.It blocks certain POST calls.I don't know which settings blocking the call.